# NullReferenceException When Getting Latest Topics and Replies For Forums in User's Clubs

Tags: episerver, episerver-6

I'm trying to query the set of forums (fora?) for the user's clubs to get the latest topics and replies in those forums. This is the code I'm using:

```
RoomCollectionCriterion userClubRoomsCollection = new RoomCollectionCriterion();

foreach (Club userClub in userClubCollection)
{
    RoomCriterion userClubRoomCriterion = new RoomCriterion();
    userClubRoomCriterion.ID = new IntegerCriterion();
    userClubRoomCriterion.ID.Value = userClub.ForumRoom.ID;

    userClubRoomsCollection.Criteria.Add(userClub.Name, userClubRoomCriterion);
}

TopicQuery topicQuery = new TopicQuery();

topicQuery.Room = new RoomCriterion();
// Pass in our collection of the user's clubs to the query
topicQuery.Room.Rooms = userClubRoomsCollection;

MessageCollection topics = QueryHandler.GetQueryResult<EPiServer.Community.Forum.Topic, MessageCollection>(topicQuery, pageNumber, 2);
MessageCollection replies = QueryHandler.GetQueryResult<EPiServer.Community.Forum.Topic, MessageCollection>(topicQuery, pageNumber, 4);
```

The problem I have is that every time I hit the first call to `GetQueryResult`, I get a `NullReferenceException`. I can't see anything wrong/missing with what I'm passing in to `GetQueryResult`, but I'm hoping somebody else has done this previously and can suggest a fix for this.

Update 26/10/2010
As suggested by Magnus I swapped out my `QueryHandler.GetQueryResult` for a call to `ForumHandler.GetQueryResult` but this doesn't seem to have made a difference. I've also trimmed down the parameters to `GetQueryResult` so that my line of code is now:

```
MessageCollection topics = ForumHandler.GetQueryResult(topicQuery);
```

but this still gives me a NullReferenceException. Which suggests to me the problem isn't in the GetQueryResult method of whichever handler I'm calling, it's in the `topicQuery` object, as that's the thing that's stayed constant so far. I'm wondering if I'm missing a property that needs to be set on the `TopicQuery` object.

Update 4/11/2010
Is there a "security context" that needs consideration here? i.e. the query needs to be run in the context of a user that has complete access to all forums?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this (as found by my colleague) is:

```
TopicQuery topicQuery = new TopicQuery();

//For latest topics we want to sort by the topics creation date.
topicQuery.CreateDate = new DateTimeCriterion();
topicQuery.Room = new RoomCriterion();
topicQuery.Room.ID = new IntegerCriterion();
//We want to include several roomIDs
topicQuery.Room.ID.Includes = new IntegerInCriterion();

//For each club, get its ForumRoom
foreach (Club userClub in userClubCollection)
{
    topicQuery.Room.ID.Includes.Values.Add(userClub.ForumRoom.ID);
}

//Sorting of results
CriterionSortOrder critSort = new CriterionSortOrder(topicQuery.CreateDate, EPiServer.Common.Sorting.SortingDirection.Descending);

//Add sorting to query
topicQuery.OrderBy.Add(critSort);

MessageCollection topics = QueryHandler.GetQueryResult<EPiServer.Community.Forum.Topic, MessageCollection>(topicQuery, 1, 2);
topicQuery.OrderBy.Remove(critSort);

//For Latest replies we want to sort topics by LastReply.CreateDate. Therefore we add this. 
topicQuery.LastReply = new ReplyCriterion();
topicQuery.Replies = new ReplyCollectionCriterion();
topicQuery.Replies.Count = new IntegerCriterion();
topicQuery.Replies.Count.Operator = ComparisonOperator.GreaterThan | ComparisonOperator.Equals;
topicQuery.Replies.Count.Value = 1;
topicQuery.LastReply.CreateDate = new DateTimeCriterion();
CriterionSortOrder critSort2 = new CriterionSortOrder(topicQuery.LastReply.CreateDate, EPiServer.Common.Sorting.SortingDirection.Descending);

topicQuery.OrderBy.Add(critSort2);
MessageCollection replies = QueryHandler.GetQueryResult<EPiServer.Community.Forum.Topic, MessageCollection>(topicQuery, 1, 4);

lvMyEntries.DataSource = topics;
lvMyEntries.DataBind();
lvMyReplies.DataSource = replies;
lvMyReplies.DataBind();
```

The key point here appears to be the use of the `IntegerInCriterion` which I'm inferring from the name allows you submit a set of integers to be used in the query in a criterion (like a SQL `IN` clause I guess).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `EPiServer.Community.Forum.ForumHandler.GetQueryResult()` and its overloads.

Comment: No joy. I swapped out my line for `MessageCollection topics = EPiServer.Community.Forum.ForumHandler.GetQueryResult(topicQuery, pageNumber, 2);` but I get the same NullReferenceException :-(